# Recursion in String Length of Roman Numeral

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I am new to Wolfram language (Mathematica) programming, I have below problems.

To summarise the problem :
The input is a positive integer, and the output is a recursive list of the lengths of the Roman numerals of input x. Stop the list when the list starts to repeat.

For example :
`StringLength[RomanNumeral[#]] &@123` gives 6;
`StringLength[RomanNumeral[#]] &@6` gives 2
(Stop here, because the function starts to repeat afterwards 2);
`StringLength[RomanNumeral[#]] &@2` gives 2.
So, the correct output for x=123 should be a list {123, 6, 2}

```
 romanListLength[x_Integer?Positive] := 
 NestWhileList[StringLength[RomanNumeral[#]] &, x, DuplicateFreeQ]
```

and I tested for 123, and get error message:
[image]

I appreciate if anyone can help

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `FixedPointList`satisfies your need. Can you try the following?

```
romanListLength[x_Integer?Positive] := FixedPointList[StringLength[RomanNumeral[#]] &, x]
```

Comment: `romanListLength2[x_Integer?Positive] := 
 Most@FixedPointList[StringLength[RomanNumeral[#]] &, x]`, added 'Most' as bbgodfrey suggested, then the duplicate element is removed. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`DuplicateFreeQ` in the code is applied to the each value computed by `NestWhileList`, not to the cumulative `List` of values computed.  To achieve the goal of the question, compare the current value computed with preceding ones.

```
romanListLength[x_Integer?Positive] := 
    Most@NestWhileList[StringLength[RomanNumeral[#]] &, x, UnsameQ, All]
```

Then,

```
romanListLength[123]
(* {123, 6, 2} *)
```

as desired.  (`Most` discards the last value, which always is a duplicate.)  Here are some more values.

```
Table[romanListLength[n], {n, 25}]
(* {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}, {8, 4, 2}, {9, 2}, 
    {10, 1}, {11, 2}, {12, 3}, {13, 4, 2}, {14, 3}, {15, 2}, {16, 3}, 
    {17, 4, 2}, {18, 5, 1}, {19, 3}, {20, 2}, {21, 3}, {22, 4, 2}, 
    {23, 5, 1}, {24, 4, 2}, {25, 3}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. The code works.